# How to reset the touches queue?

Tags: cocoa-touch

How do I make the iPhone forget about UITouch events, or simulate a `touchesCancelled` event?

Answer (score 0):

There is an *undocumented* method `-_cancelAllTouches` in UIApplication which will cancel all active touches.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _cancelAllTouches];
```

Otherwise, I don't see a documented method to reliably get all active touches.